# I cannot add any file to Firebase Storage with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="file" id="dosya" @change="putDesign()" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ,
  authDomain: ,
  databaseURL: ,
  projectId: ,
  storageBucket: ,
  messagingSenderId: ,
  appId: ,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fileName: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    putDesign() {
      this.fileName = document.getElementById("dosya").files[0].name;
      const designRef = ref(storage, "design/" + this.fileName);
      designRef.put(this.fileName);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Hello friends, I am trying to add files to Firebase Storage, but it gives me this error: designRef is not a function. I tried some other ways too that I found on internet, but I couldn't make it. How can I add files to Firestore Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Modular SDK doesn't have a `put()` method. You need to use `uploadBytes`. Also, the file itself must be passed instead of just filename:

```
const file = document.getElementById("dosya").files[0]
this.fileName = file.name;
const designRef = ref(storage, "design/" + this.fileName);

uploadBytes(designRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded:', file.name);
});
```

Comment: I saw this on Firebase Documentation, but it doesn't work. it says: snapshot defined but never used.

Comment: @OzanBilgiç that's a Typescript warning.. try: `.then(() => { ..}` if you don't need Snapshot